# Multi tenant in Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, multi-tenant

Looking to build a CRM type application and need to separate the data for each client in the firestore database.

Whats the best way to structure the data?

If we take a few basic collections for this example... `company`, `user`, `account`, `product`.

- A user is simply the user of the application i'm building.
- This `user` would work for a `company` that employs them.
- The `user` would then look to sell `product`s to `account`s.

Generally to handle this should I be placing

- `company` at the root level.
- Then `user`, `account` and `product` underneath `company`.

Im unsure whats best security wise and/or normal convention.

Comment: In general there aren't any convention apart from the [Firestore best practices](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices), any extra layer should be implemented in your code on top of the Firebase database. These two articles [1](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/multi-tenant-applications-with-firebase-and-google-cloud-4d0d02b7d859) [2](https://christianlydemann.com/setting-up-a-multi-tenant-application-with-firebase-graphql-and-angular/) might be helpful for your use case.